# Prevent back slash escaping from the string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a code which replaces the back slashes as empty string

```
var data = '<strong>Welcome</strong>\(x = {-b';
document.write(data);
```

**I am getting result like this:**

**Welcome**(x = {-b

**I am expecting result like this without modifying string value**

**Welcome**\(x = {-b

I used the same string to display in an id as html content.

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '<strong>Welcome</strong>\(x = {-b';
```

It always replacing slashes by empty string. the string.split method did not helped me to solve this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var data = '<strong>Welcome</strong>\\(x = {-b';
document.write(data);
```

try this...

Comment: If srting is dynamic, you've to use replace function

Comment: replace function is not supporting for single slash what can i do

Comment: '<strong>Welcome</strong>\\(x = {-b'.replace("\", "\\"); I am getting error while using using this

Comment: Chwck this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870872/escaping-escape-characters

Comment: This regex cheat sheet might help you. https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html